# Why won't Google Tag Manager's Macro pass object content of a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, google-tag-manager

So I have a custom javascript variable in GTM:

```js
function(){
  var products = {{dlv ecommerce products}};
  var prodinfo = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < products.length; i++){
        prodinfo.push({
          'subTotal': products[i].price,
          'category': products[i].category,
          'sku': products[i].id,
          'quantity': products[i].quantity,
          'name': products[i].name
        });
    }
  return prodinfo;
}
```

I am having this code running for my Event event_process and it is pushed to the data layer successfully populating in that event for the debugger:

```
[
  {
    subTotal: '149.99',
    category: 'main-product',
    sku: 'WB36',
    quantity: 1,
    name: 'The Revolutionary Wombo'
  },
  {
    subTotal: '0',
    category: 'accessory',
   sku: 'LL550',
   quantity: 1,
   name: '7-day warranty'
 }]
```

The Google Analytics Tag successfully shows this information in the debugger but the debugger for my custom HTML Tag:

```
"[object, Object],[object Object]"
```

and the network doesn't seem to be picking up the key value pairs. The tag is firing on the correct event and other tags are picking up the array of objects, so I am just stumped as to why this tag cannot display the objects in the array. The only thing I can think of is maybe custom HTML Tags do not have that functionality but I have seen no discussion of this issue at all online.

Comment: if  you see this on the screen with a data layer you should be able to  read it without a script 
do you still have this problem @peh